# Why does my RAID array keep changing names?

Tags: mount, raid

I have my Linux system on my SSD, and have 2 1TB HDDs set up as a RAID-0 array (for some reason it's named "Raid 0", I don't like the fact that the person who set it up put a space in the name instead of an underscore or dash, but anyway).

I set my start-up applications so that this RAID array always gets mounted 2 seconds after start-up, that way I don't have to click on it to be able to access certain bookmarks. But the name of the drive keeps changing, making the bookmarks I made pointless! The array's name was originally "Raid 0", but then became "Raid 0_", and "Raid 0__", and now it's "Raid 0______". What is going on??

Here's the output of `inxi -FGxxx` if it helps:

```
System:    Host: alborz-G750JW Kernel: 3.19.0-41-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 4.8.2)
       Desktop: Cinnamon 2.8.6 (Gtk 3.10.8) dm: mdm Distro: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G750JW v: 1.0 Bios: American Megatrends v: G750JW.210 date: 12/11/2013
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4700HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 19157
       clock speeds: min/max: 800/3400 MHz 1: 2499 MHz 2: 2504 MHz 3: 3175 MHz 4: 2400 MHz 5: 2477 MHz
       6: 2988 MHz 7: 2467 MHz 8: 2995 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:11e2
       Display Server: X.Org 1.15.1 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
       Resolution: 1600x900@60.1hz
       GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 765M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.18 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:8c20
       Card-2 NVIDIA GK106 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:0e0b
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.19.0-41-generic
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       driver: wl bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 14e4:43b1
       IF: wlan0 state: up mac: 6c:71:d9:36:60:b4
       Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       driver: alx port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 1969:10a1
       IF: eth0 state: down mac: 74:d0:2b:e9:4c:c8
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2512.5GB (9.3% used)
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB serial: S2Y4J9FD404111
       ID-2: /dev/sdb model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB serial: S2Y4J9FD404103
       ID-3: /dev/sdc model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 512.1GB serial: S1SXNSAFA14082N
Partition: ID-1: / size: 110G used: 41G (39%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc6
       ID-2: /home size: 92G used: 18G (20%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc7
       ID-3: swap-1 size: 16.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdc8
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
       No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
       Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:46C
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 235 Uptime: 1:12 Memory: 1564.5/15997.8MB
       Init: Upstart v: 1.12.1 runlevel: 2 default: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4
       Client: Shell (bash 4.3.111 running in gnome-terminal) inxi: 2.2.28 `
```

Comment: Are you using software raid? If so `mdadm --detail raid_device`, please.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm not sure what software raid is, I just told the person at the shop to make my HDDs into a RAID array and put Windows into the SSD (and he kept a part of the SSD blank for me to install Linux next to it). I just ran your command and it says `mdadm: cannot open raid_device: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Maybe it is hardware RAID then. But hardware RAID requires a RAID card. Do you have one of those? They're pretty expensive. Also, hardware RAID is likely not on-topic here, since it strictly has nothing to do with Unix.

Comment: I'm not sure if my laptop came with one or not, how can I find out?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat). Ping me if you get in there.

Comment: Since Linux sees two disks, but Linux's RAID subsystem isn't managing them, you have [fakeraid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware-_and_driver-based) — RAID which the hardware (firmware) pretends to manage but which is in fact managed by a driver, combining the downsides of software RAID (dependent on a driver, lower performance) with the downsides of hardware RAID (the disks won't work on another machine). (@FaheemMitha fakeraid is common on mid- to high-end PC motherboards.) If you can, switch to Linux's software RAID; you may need to fight your BIOS to do that.